# Mix generics with non-generics in class signature

Tags: java

I see similar questions asked for C++ and C# but not for Java. Is there a way I can define concrete types along with generics in a class signature? Something like this:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

class Foo<T, Optional<O>> {
}
```

Compiler describes this as invalid syntax.

Comment: In general, one does not need to specify the `Optional<O>`, but only `O`. We can then, for example, expect an `Optional<O>` as parameter (which we shouldn't, `Optional`s as parameters are a smell9 or return an `Optional<O>`. --- The question sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) can you be a little bit more concrete on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is invalid syntax: the stuff in the `<>` immediately after the class name are type variables, but `Optional<O>` isn't a valid name for a type variable. `Optional` would be a valid (but ill-advised) type variable name (it hides the name `Optional`, if you wanted to use that too, and would make people think it was the `java.util.Optional` type); `O` would also be valid-but-ill-advised type name (looks too much like `0`).

Comment: Perhaps either only allowing a method to return an `Optional<O>` or only providing constructors that accept an `Optional<O>` as an argument would suffice.  More information on how this is used would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the declaration of a type variable and the usage of one.

In `class Foo<T> {}`, as well as `public static <T> void foo() {}`, the `<T>` part is **declaring** the types. It's equivalent to the `x` in `public class Foo { int x; }` - you are saying that there is a type variable and it has the name T, you're not using it.

Hence, `Optional<O>` is obviously illegal there. Just like `int a + b` is gobbledygook.

You *CAN* put a bound on your typevar; just like `Number a` doesn't just declare an `a` but also limits it to be a reference to some instance of Number (or null), you can do the same when you declare types: `class Foo<T extends Number>` puts a bound on T, decreeing that it must necessarily be Number or some subtype thereof.

Thus, in theory, you could do something like:

```
class Foo<T, O extends Optional<?>> {}
```

except that makes no sense, there's no reason to ever write that code. What is your intent? That the second typevar is optional? That doesn't work in java, unfortunately. No such thing as optional typevars.

That it can be an `Optional<T>`? Just `T` is any type, including Optional, so that isn't needed.

That it *must* be an `Optional<T>`? That's 'optional abuse'. Optional isn't type-orthogonal and thus isn't that kind of flexible. You mustn't write code that way. Optionals can make sense as the return type of a method and shouldn't be used anywhere else; parameters should never be typed that way, fields should never be typed that way, and they definitely should never show up in generics. Any code that calls a method that returns an optional should immediately 'unwrap' it (e.g. by chaining an `.orElse` call).

The language spec doesn't enforce it, but the language gives you zero tools to deal with optional dichotomy. Essentially that means any API or code that works that way is going to lack abstractive powers to an incredible degree, and would feel exceedingly clunky as a result.

For example, it is **impossible** to write a method in java that accepts either `List<String>`, or `List<Optional<String>>`, but not e.g. `List<Optional<Number>>`, and can operate on the provided list regardless. Eventhough that is an operation that makes perfect sense: You can trivially have a method that for example only reads from the list (never calls `.add` or `.addAll` or whatnot on the list), and when it reads, does nullchecks (which would be pointless for a list that contains never-null strings, but it doesn't harm anything). Or, the method does invoke `.add`, but always adds non-null things. adding a guaranteed not null string is a legal move on a 'list of never null strings' and also a legal move on 'list of could-be-null string refs', and yet, java doesn't let you write this method: That's why you shouldn't treat optional as a type-in-flight; APIs cannot deal with the dichotomy.

And yet, you can't write this in java or just about any other language that supports Optional. That's just one example, there are many, they all point to the same thing: Optional? Only sensible as return values from methods, and must be unwrapped immediately; any other usage of them is harmful and silly: Leads to bugs and code that is hard to maintain, and isn't particularly flexible (is hard to adapt to changing requirements).